# Layer(s) not valid using QGIS WMS Server

Tags: qgis, postgresql, wms, qgis-server

I am trying to setup a QGIS WMS Server and populate it with data from my PostgreSQL database but I keep getting

```
CRITICAL Server[45873]: Error, Layer(s) geometry_lines_ff7beec1_d15f_4b53_abb3_ece34b23a625 not valid in project /home/ubuntu/data.qgz
15:22:29 WARNING Server[45873]: <ServerException>Layer(s) not valid</ServerException>
```

in '/var/log/qgis/qgisserver.log' when doing a `GetProjectSettings` request.

It's most certainly a database connection issue as everything worked fine when getting the layer from a file instead, and there is no problem when retrieving the layer from the postgresql database on QGIS Desktop.

I had issues with the authentication db before but it should be fixed as I don't have any error in my apache logs. Here are the logs just in case :

```
[Thu Mar 07 15:03:07.734416 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 84765:tid 139791237266496] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Mar 07 15:03:07.838939 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 86897:tid 139707940244544] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 07 15:03:07.839028 2024] [core:notice] [pid 86897:tid 139707940244544] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
Application path not initialized
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-www-data'
Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver JP2ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Initializing server modules from  "/usr/lib/qgis/server"

"Checking /usr/lib/qgis/server for native services modules"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libdummy.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwcs.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwfs.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwfs3.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwms.so"
"Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwmts.so"
static bool LibSecretKeyring::findPassword(const QString&, const QString&, QKeychain::JobPrivate*)
```

I have set a PGSERVICEFILE like this: SetEnv PGSERVICEFILE /home/ubuntu/.pg_service.conf, and it seems correct as the command `psql service=myservice` is successful.

I also tried changing file permissions to have no restriction but it didn't help.